# How does this list comprehension produces this output?

Tags: haskell, list-comprehension

I was dealing with some Haskell function examples but I didn't understand this particular function:

```
f x = [not a | a<-[x,not x], a]
```

and it produces `[False]` as output but I didn't understand why. Can one please explain this in detail?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This list comprehension consists out of three parts:

```
   [ not a | a <- [x, not x], a ]
--   ^ yield ^ generator      ^ filter
```

The ***generator*** thus lets `a` *iterate* over a list with two elements. Those elements are `[True,False]` or `[False,True]` (depending on the value of `x`). But thus always the same values (only the order of the elements is different).

Next the ***filter*** part comes in `a`. A filter *retains the values for which the predicate is `True`*. Here the predicate is simply `a`: so it retains configurations for which `a = True`. Since both `True` and `False` for `a` are enumerated, it means that we will only take *one* item into account: the one where `a` is `True`.

For that value, we ***yield*** `not a`. Now `not True` is of course `False`. So as a result, regardless of the value of `x` (as long as it is `True` or `False`), we will always generate `[False]`.

So as a result:

```
Prelude> let f x = [not a | a<-[x,not x], a]
Prelude> f True
[False]
Prelude> f False
[False]
```

Comment: Thank you! so if the **yield part was `a` and the filter was `not a` the result would be `[TRUE]`** right ?. Also why "A filter only retains the values for which the predicate is `True` "? Is it a rule because if its just `a` what first came to my mind is that it can be any value. Can you explain that **filter** part please

Comment: @Snxby: no because if the filter is `not a`, then only `a = False` would be allowed, and we thus would yield `a` and thus that would again result in `[False]`.

Comment: @Snxby You ask why list comprehension filters only retain values where the predicate gives `True`. There are two possible answers here, depending on what question you intended to ask. If you intended to ask "how do you know that this is the behavior", the answer is to [look in the Report](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch3.html#x8-420003.11). If you intended to ask "why was this behavior chosen", the answer is because keeping just some elements of a list is a common need, and this is a natural and simple way to address that need.

Comment: @Snxby You propose that "if its just `a` it can be any value". But that's not so, for two reasons: first, `a` is defined by drawing an element from the list `[x, not x]`, and since `not` always returns a `Bool`, we can know that `a` is definitely a `Bool`; and second, because `a` is used as a filter and filters are always `Bool`-valued expressions, we can again know that `a` is a `Bool` (and report an error if this is in conflict with how `a` was defined!).

Answer (score 1):

You can also understand this with equational reasoning. Start with the list comprehension:

```
f x = [not a | a <- [x, not x], a]
```

Desugar to the list monad:

```
f x = do
  a <- [x, not x]
  guard a
  pure (not a)
```

Desugar `do` notation:

```
f x = [x, not x] >>= \ a -> guard a >> return (not a)
```

Inline the definition of `>>=` for lists:

```
f x = concatMap (\ a -> guard a >> return (not a)) [x, not x]
```

Inline `guard`/`>>`:

```
f x = concatMap (\ a -> if a then return (not a) else []) [x, not x]
```

Inline `return`:

```
f x = concatMap (\ a -> if a then [not a] else []) [x, not x]
```

Expand `concatMap g xs` to `concat (map g xs)`:

```
f x = concat (map (\ a -> if a then [not a] else []) [x, not x])
```

Inline `map`:

```
f x = concat
  [ if x then [not x] else []
  , if not x then [not (not x)] else []
  ]
```

Note that `if x then [not x] else []` evaluates to `[False]` if `x` is `True` and `[]` if `x` is `False`, and that `if not x then [not (not x)] else []` evaluates to `[]` if `x` is `True` and `[False]` if `x` is `False`. Therefore you have:

```
f x = if x then [False] ++ [] else [] ++ [False]
```

And since `[False] ++ [] == [] ++ [False] == [False]`, you get:

```
f x = [False]
```